# How to show the scroll percentage of the Scroll Depth Analytics module

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed & configured the [Scroll Depth Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/scroll_depth_analytics) module on my website. I get the output as shown in below image:

[image]

I want to get the page title in the event label field so that I can see scroll percentage for an individual page.

Or else is there any way to see the scroll percentage with the path of the page next to it.